# How can I convert 2 comma separated strings into a table/Datatable using C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I am using C# ASP.NET. I have 2 comma-separated strings (Name and Quantity) in my C# code behind file.

```
string Name = "Apple,Samsung";
string Quantity = "24,20";
```

I want to add this data to a table/dataTable, mapping the first name to the first quantity and the second name to the second quantity:

[image: Click to view Table]

Hardcoding these into different rows is not an option as my data keeps changing and it might have several other rows too.

Is there a way I can split these two comma-separated strings and add into a DataTable?

Comment: What kind of data table are you talking about? [A literal `DataTable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datatable)? Please describe your goal.

Comment: Sorry if it was unclear from my question.More accurately, I mean a tabular view of the data. I read the use of DataTable so I thought it would be the way to go in C#.

Comment: We need to know what framework you're using for your GUI (Razor Mvc, Winforms, Xamarin Forms, WPF, ...). Please tag your question appropriately.

Comment: If it keeps changing it seems that it should be stored in a database, file, etc. instead of compiled into your application.  Otherwise, I think you're focused on "How do I extract this data stored as comma-separated strings?" when that might not be the best/only solution.  Are you familiar with arrays?

Comment: Your question is probably too broad. You need to present [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). It's not clear what exactly is your problem? Are you asking about parsing the string or presenting a table or something else?

Answer (score 1):

Please try if this solve your problem:

```
            string Name = "Apple,Samsung";
            string Quantity = "24,20";

            string[] names = Name.Split(',');
            string[] quantities = Quantity.Split(',');

            DataTable table = new DataTable();
            table.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));
            table.Columns.Add("Quantity", typeof(string));

            for (int i = 0; i < names.Length; i++)
                table.Rows.Add(new object[] { names[i], quantities[i] });
```

Comment: tried it but can't seem to visualize it

Comment: put a break point at the end of the method and inspect the table object